# How to convert all rows in JupyterLab with '%sql'?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am so confused and need your help.

I work in a company, and I also use company's JupyterLab servers and resources. Today I connect company's database, then I want to convert all the query results of the database into a dataframe. This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd;
pd.set_option('display.max_rows',None);
pd.set_option('display.max_columns',None);
df=%sql select * from database.xxx;
table=df.Dataframe();
```

After that, I write

```
 table.shape[0]
```

to check the number of rows. **But it shows only 500. The dataset should have been over 10,000 rows.**

I try to write directly like that:

```
%sql select * from database.xxx;
```

It also shows 500 rows and says, "**500 rows,truncated to displaylimit of 200.**"

I check code and find that when I connect the database, it says,"**Database connected, autolimit set to 500. Database connected, displaylimit set to 200.**"

I want to convert all the rows. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Change your autolimit configuration (this seems rather obvious, given the message `autolimit set to 500`): https://jupysql.ploomber.io/en/latest/api/configuration.html

Comment: @topsail OK, fine. I am a new one in JupyterLab.